# How to extract and transform filename from org-mode link with PostgreSQL regex?

Tags: postgresql, hyperlink, regexp-replace

[`org-mode` file links](https://orgmode.org/guide/Hyperlinks.html) are generally of the form

`[[/path/to/file][text description]]`.

What regex do I need to extract `/path/to/file` so I can produce strings like `file:///path/to/file` or `file:///path/to/file:linenum` so I can click on a link to open the file in an editor.